# How to organize dependencies in Visual Studio 2010 C++ best?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dependency-management

I am new to Visual Stuido and I want to know how to organize the dependencies of a project in Visual Studio 2010 C++ (Express Edition) best.

The main problem is the following:
A project P requires lib L, so I add dependecy L to P. L is somewhere located at my system. I submit P to our version control. My colleague  checks P out, but the configuration of P does not fit to his system (L is located somewhere else at his system). So he adjusts the configuration and submits the changes to P. I check P out and now it does not fit to my system.

I come from Java and Eclipse. In Eclipse you can set a variable globally for the whole IDE f.e. PATH_TO_L. In the project configuration the dependency is now variable PATH_TO_L and not anymore a path. So my colleague and I can use the exact same sources including the project configuration. All we have to do is to set both the variable PATH_TO_L. Nice.

Even nicer is Maven. So you do not have to care about copying the right dependencies to the right locations, because Maven does all the work for you.

I searched a little bit for a solution. One possible solution would be to use Property Sheets and to add a template Property Sheet to our version control. But templates in version control are not comfortable to use and I would have to adjust the settings for every project. Not a global setting.

I tried to use system environment variables, but I think Visual Studio 2010 does not use them.

So here is the question. How do you organize your projects in Visual Studio 2010? Is there an ideal way? Is there something like Maven, or is there a possibilty to use an repository manager like nexus in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, with the property sheets.
You could use a property sheet to reference a environment variable. An example is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak4435es).
I would add the Path of library to the user specific property file named `Microsoft.Cpp.<platform>.user`. As this is included by default. More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621.aspx).

As soon as you get familiar with the property sheets it not as bad as it seems. I actually start to like the msbuild system. But I am not aware of anything like maven for msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot of people are using meta-build systems, these days, such as CMake, SCons...

Amongst other useful features, you can set up some variables that you can later reuse, for example for paths. This way, your colleague and yourself will have the same CMake configuration, but with individualised paths.

And, as these scripts are simple text files, they play nicely with version control (much better than MSVC xml configuration)